# OWASP-ZAP baseline scan: configuration file, set severity

Tags: owasp, zap

I am using the ZAP docker image to run a Baseline Scan (= passive scan) using OWASP=ZAP and generate a report.

I want however to change all [Warn] Rules to [Ignore]. There should be a configuration file with all possible messages and its severity. Where is this Configuration File located and how should I change it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the published docs, https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/baseline-scan/ :

`-g gen_file       generate default config file (all rules set to WARN)`

It's just a text file so edit it and use it:

```
-c config_file    config file to use to INFO, IGNORE or FAIL warnings
-u config_url     URL of config file to use to INFO, IGNORE or FAIL warnings
```

For example:

`docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t https://www.example.com -c /zap/wrk/my.conf -r /zap/wrk/testreport.html`

Where my.conf is in the mapped pwd, then the report is written there as well.

Comment: Great, thanks for letting us know.